# Remove the "-target" suffix from the output dist directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8

I have the requirement to remove the dash (`-`) from the filenames of the `dist/` files. The reason is that the system where the app needs to be deployed does not accept dashes.

Can this be done? I remember older version of Angular did not add the `-target` to the filename and that's where I'm trying to get to. Instead of having a `dist/` folder with files in the format `main-es2015.js`, etc., I would like to have the files named `main.js`, etc., or at least remove the dash character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it by disabling angular new feature **conditional loading**
see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading) for more info.